# Where is the scroll gone in Adobe PDF viewer?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

So I am attempting to view a document and on the left hand side is a table of contents but unfortunately I am unable to locate a scroll bar or next-page button for this table of contents.

Is there such an interface included and if so how do I find it?[image]

Comment: What happens when you give the bookmarks panel the focus (click into it) and then try to scroll? What happens when you unfold a chapter in the bookmarks panel? What happens when you switch to the Pages panel and back? And finally what happens when you restart Reader?

Comment: When I click onto it nothing appears to change it is simply cut off at the last element it can display and no scrolling device or "hand grabbing device" is present for scrolling. Unfolding a chapter simply highlights that chapter on the page and nothing else. Switching doesn't reveal anything either. And this problem appears to persist after restarting as well.

Comment: Is this the right forum for this or is there a better stackexchange to post this question on?

Comment: If you haven't already, you might also ask at answers.acrobatusers.com, the user-to-user answers forum for Acrobat and PDF.

Answer (score 3):

As of Adobe Reader 11.0.19, whether scrollbars are display is related to if touch mode is enabled.

I see from your screenshot that you have touch mode enabled. When you disabled the touch mode, the scrollbars appear. (The example depicts Page Thumbnail panel, but this also applies with Bookmarks / Table of Contents.)

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

You can also configure if Touch mode if enabled on Adobe Reader startup: Edit menu -> Preferences -> General -> Touch mode.